# Block a domain (with all domains) system-wide

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip, domain

I'm trying to block my computer from "accidentally" sending any requests to a certain domain I don't trust (and all of it's subdomains). I tried adding this entry to my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.0       google.com
```

And in fact, after the DNS cache wears off or is flushed, all requests to the domain fail, because they resolve to local address instead of the real one. Unfortunately, requests to a *sub*domain of the domain still are not blocked.

What's the best way to block/disable all the subdomain as well?

Comment: Do you know about Linux firewall ('ufw)'?

Comment: I know it can be used to block the incoming traffic. Can it also prevent my computer from *sending* request to a specific remote host? Also, does it support blocking based on domain?

Comment: I find it unlikely - I suppose it only works on the ip layer, after dns resolution

Comment: Did you use **whois**? This would give you a subnet. 1.1.1.2/20   If all the domains track back to the same subnet you could use iptables to block the subnet easily.

Comment: I have no guarantee that all of the subdomains lead to the same subnet...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "hosts" file does not support wildcards (*.example.com).
So to do this you will need something a bit more involved - like blocking the domain through some security software or by running your own DNS server / resolver.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of such software for GNU/Linux od provide some hints on how to configure it?

Comment: Not sure what client security packages are available for Linux (I use Windows). But I would asume that something similar to Norton Internet Security exists...  Sorry don't know of any specifics. But you can certainly do it with a local DNS server. For Linux, BIND is the ("named") first one that comes to mind. There are tons of articles on how to configure this...

Answer (score 0):

Check you router. Some of them let you block sites by domains or keywords and they cover subdomains as well.
The feature can be found under various names like "Block Sites", "Parental Control" etc.

Comment: I want these changes to apply only to my computer and on all networks that it connects to. I guess that router config doesn't allow for that....